# Is it possible to save levels on google play games services?

Tags: android, google-play-games

I already know about leaderboards and saved games on google play games services and I'm using it on my game. Except with these - I just want to store my game user's current level to using google cloud api. Is there any easy methods?

Also, is there any chance to get both the user's unlocked levels list & current level?

Comment: Have you looked at the Saved Games API? https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/savedgames

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your requirements correctly, the [Saved Games](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/savedgames) API can store the information you want to.  The API is basically a blob store.  So if you serialize the player's current level, unlocked level list and any other state information, you can load it again (even from a different device).

You can refer to the sample [CollectAllTheStars2](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples/CollectAllTheStars2), which saves a multi-level game state by serializing to json then saving the bytes using the Saved Games API.